# Обработка клика и вызова функции в другом потоке с помощью rxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Пробовал вот так, но получаю ошибку

```
RxView.clicks(btnSend)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object o) {
                        someNetworkFunc();
                    }
                });


"Must be called from the main thread".
```

Comment: Что делает функция ```someNetworkFunc()```?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё добавить `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Comment: @temq какой-то сетевой запрос, который должен совершаться в отдельном потоке

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал, не получилось. Та же ошибка

Comment: там только сетевой запрос, или происходит работа с UI?

Comment: Покажите что внутри `RxView.clicks(btnSend)`

Comment: @temq только сетевой

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 
  public static Observable<Object> clicks(@NonNull View view) {
    return Observable.create(new ViewClickOnSubscribe(view));
  }

Comment: @Shodan, ну.. Боюсь, что ошибка исчезнет, если вы пропишите  `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, т.е. с кликом будете в UI треде работать. Тогда, возможно, надо ещё добавить `.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`... Так, может быть, заработает...